# Mann Kendall test in R with missing data

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, kendall-tau

I am trying to run a Mann Kendall test on community dissimilarity for streams sampled roughly monthly, but with NA values for some months where conditions prevented data collection.  From what I am reading, the Mann Kendall test should be able to handle these missing values, but I am getting the following error.

```
> mk.test(dissim.avg.ts,alternative="greater", continuity=F)
Error in na.fail.default(x) : missing values in object
```

Can anyone explain to me what is causing the problem here and how to address it?

Comment: I cannot find the source of your claim `should be able to handle these missing values`, are you sure this is true? Have you tried manually removing the missing values?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue making the calculations in general, although the performance of the test will suffer with increasing numbers of missing values.  The following link is where I had read about the specific tests in R, but on closer inspection, it's not clear if that part of the text refers to the trend or kendall package.
However, it's a time series data set, so when I remove the values before creating the time series, it bumps data points up to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Mann-Kendall test does allow missing values (see Gilbert 1987); however, documentation for the R mk.test function indicates that the current version is for complete observations only (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/trend/versions/1.1.1/topics/mk.test). Try the MannKendall function in the Kendall package.

Comment: Shoot, I just realized the source I had read that in references both packages and it isn't clear which they are referring to when they make that statement.  I'll try the other package, thanks!